# How to connect the database (SQLServer) in a Project of Flutter

Tags: sql-server, flutter

I want to connect the database of the company in flutter project and I can't find a good approach to do it.

Now, I'm trying to create a simple login/register and I don't know how I can validate without the data of the DB.

Comment: What exactly is the question

Answer (score -1):

To connect to your SQL Server database in Visual Studio start a new project and bring up Server Explorer either by clicking on the tab next to the Toolbox or by going to View > Server Explorer. Right click on 'Data Connections' then click 'Add Connection'.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the question is about programmatically connecting the Flutter app to SQL Server, not including it in the same solution.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).